Why does scipy.sparse_matrix not accept values directly from a dataframe?
I create a scipy sparse matrix that works fine
X = csr_matrix(
    (df["rating"], (item_idx, user_idx)), 
    shape=(M, N)
)

But to simplify where (roughly equivalent)
item_idx ~= df[item_id]

I do the following
csr_matrix(
    (df["points"], 
    (df["user_id"], df["item_id"])])), 
    shape=(N, M)
)

which returns an error about index and size of sparse matrix. Note that this error occurs even when the "id" is mapped to exactly the number of unique names.
ValueError: axis 0 index 99 exceeds matrix dimension 97

Can anyone help me understand why an index error would be returned here, when only the order of the values change? the range is consistent. Does it have to do with sparsity?
MRE:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user_id": np.random.randint(0, 75, 300),
    "item_id": np.random.randint(0, 100, 300),
    "rating": np.random.randint(0, 10, 300)
})


def mappings(df, user_id, item_id):
    user_id_idx_mapping = dict(zip( df[user_id].unique(), range(df[user_id].nunique()) ))
    user_idx_id_mapping = dict(zip( range(df[user_id].nunique()), df[user_id].unique() ))

    item_id_idx_mapping = dict(zip( df[item_id].unique(), range(df[item_id].nunique()) ))
    item_idx_id_mapping = dict(zip( range(df[item_id].nunique()), df[item_id].unique() ))

    return user_id_idx_mapping, user_idx_id_mapping, item_id_idx_mapping, item_idx_id_mapping

user_id_idx_mapping, user_idx_id_mapping, item_id_idx_mapping, item_idx_id_mapping = mappings(df, "user_id", "item_id")

N = df["user_id"].nunique()
M = df["item_id"].nunique()

user_idx = [user_id_idx_mapping[int(j)] for j in df["user_id"]]
item_idx = [item_id_idx_mapping[int(l)] for l in df["item_id"]]    

true = dict(zip([int(k) for k in list(df["user_id"].values)], user_idx))

X_works = csr_matrix(
    (df["rating"], (item_idx, user_idx)), 
    shape=(M, N)
)

X_doesnt = csr_matrix(
    (df["rating"], (df["item_id"], df["user_id"])), 
    shape=(M, N)
)

print(true)


Maybe I'm missing something here, but one approach is using item_idx which is a range of values from 0 to nunique, while the other is using the values themselves which may or may not have gaps.

What does  csr_matrix(     (df["rating"], (df["item_id"], df["user_id"]))) produce?  i.e. letting it set the shape from the indices?

@hpaulj this works. Thank you, that's very helpful. Ironically, it produces a matrix of shape N, M; (in this example that would be of shape (100, 75)) whereas specifying the shape as N, M actually produces a matrix (97, 75). So it must be because of gaps? @ Anonymous but my MRE produces examples that should have no gaps, correct? Unless I mis-typed something.

ah! I see. random.int problem. So it's because of the missing values.

This still seems like an unnecessary step, though, Is there any way to map the number of uniques to the value, rather than iterating through a dictionary?

Looping over every element in your DataFrame will be much slower than using pd.factorize(). Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79276553/sparse-matrix-in-pandas-scipy-with-row-and-column-indices/79276740#79276740

If you don't specify the shape, it deduces it from the largest index values.

Did you actually examine the N,M produced by nunique?  randint must have had duplicates and even gaps, even with 300 samples.

@NickODell is this method faster than simply iterating thru a mapping dictionary to get the indices? What a find.

@hpaulj exactly right

@plotmaster473 It was roughly 6x faster on the example I tried.

@NickODell just confirmed, about ~6 x faster. noice.

The shape need to be bigger than the highest index (the values in the dataframe). You are getting the error
ValueError: axis 0 index 99 exceeds matrix dimension 97

since column item_id has the value 99 but the value of M is 97
print(M, N)
print(max(item_idx), max(user_idx))
print(max(df["item_id"]), max(df["user_id"]))
    
Output:

96 75
95 74
99 74

You need to make sure the shape is big enough. One option (not sure it's what exactly you are looking for) is to take the max between (M, N) and the values in the columns
shape = max(M, max(df["item_id"])+1), max(N, max(df["user_id"])+1)


got it. So IDs need to have a range specified specifically for this call, as the CSR matrix is created from that range. Therefore, if my range is off, the shape won't fit the IDs.

When I run your code I get:
In [195]: N,M
Out[195]: (74, 96)

The actual numbers will vary depending on the random numbers generated.
When I create your matrices, without specifying (N,M), I get:
In [196]: X_works
Out[196]: 
<96x74 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 294 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [197]: X_doesnt
Out[197]: 
<100x75 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 294 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Those are different sizes.  One makes the (N,M) size, based on the number of unique indices, the other (100,75) based on the maximum values of the indices.  With a sample of 300, there's a good chance that there will be at least one value at the maximum range, but a greater chance that there will be some gaps.  And of course duplicates.
Note that the stored values is 294, less than the generated 300.  There are some duplicates which are summed.
Besides the shape differences, the layout of values in the 2 matrices is totally different.  Print the repective indices yourself.  Or look at something like
X_works[:10,:10].toarry()

or
print(X_doesnt[:10,:10])

